# How exactly is time series regression useful to market participant?

Tags: regression

Assume we run an OLS regression with dependent variable of 3-month holding period returns of a stock, and independent variable of 10 year treasury yields.

Assume regression coefficient is 2, so for every 1% point rise in 10 year yield, we expect a 2% rise the 3-month return of our stock.

Since the coefficient explains the relationship between past 3-month returns and treasury yields, how exactly does that provide any insight to a market participant who always holds for 3 months and then sells the stock? Or does it not provide any insight?

Comment: In my opinion it does not provide any insight, perhaps I am missing something. Usually we look for predictive regressions: variable(s) known at time t that can predict stock returns between t and t+h.

Comment: I’m not trying to predict anything. I want to explain the relationship between stock returns at each holding period and the monthly 10 year yield. So I want to be able to say “1% rise in monthly treasury yield means a 2% rise in 1-month holding period return;” “1% rise in monthly treasury yield means a 5% rise in 3-month holding period return,” etc. Does that make sense? I want to see the sensitivity of the returns, by holding period, to changes in monthly treasury yield.

Comment: So I’m asking if my regression is a valid way of describing that sensitivity.

Comment: Yes, that regression coefficient is your sensitivity that you are looking for. That coefficient is also called beta. Here is an article that walks through the beta calc and talks about some of its implications. https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/070615/what-formula-calculating-beta.asp

Comment: Thank you! And that beta makes sense if I use a 3-month return with the monthly treasury yield? I suppose one could use anything as independent variable (the interpretation would simply change).

Comment: Never mind. My English is not the best. I understand now.

Comment: I think your question is really very much the same as this [one](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/65820/54838). Especially the bullet points at the end. If you assert stock returns explain treasury yields, that the relationship is linear and believe nothing else will affect them, it will be valid. If you think this is not the case, it will essentially show you the correlation between these two, which may be entirely coincidental. Generally it seems if OLS is done, it is the [other way around](https://www.uv.es/bfc/TFM2016/TFM_AdrianMaizonadaBenigno.pdf) -how interest rates affect stock return

Comment: Agreed. Thank you.

Comment: But this is what I am saying, no? I am modeling sensitivity if returns to treasury yield. How am I doing backwards? My DV is returns, and my IV is treasury yields.

Comment: Sorry, I should have read this more carefully, you are correct. Generally, it's like regressing crop yield and hours of sunshine. It's potentially useful, but location, precipitation, fertilizers, soil, diseases and pests etc are having a big impact on crop yields. If you don't take these into account, your results are almost certainly biased because it is sunshine and everything else that matters that results in your single parameter estimate. If you just have these two variables, you claim leadership, age of firm, size, firm structure, competitors, profit margins, ... all play no role.